# Import CSV spreadsheet slow

Tags: import, excel, spreadsheets

```
Ydata = Import[
     FPath <> "TEK" <> IntegerString[4, 10, 4] <> ".CSV", {"Data", #, 
      5}] & /@ Range[2500];
Xdata = Import[
     FPath <> "TEK" <> IntegerString[4, 10, 4] <> ".CSV", {"Data", #, 
      4}] & /@ Range[2500];
```

Importing CSV files takes around 8-10 minutes per file, which is ridiculously slow, for a 74KB file, with 2500 rows of data and 2 column data. Is there anyway to speed it up? CSV is a file which can be opened by excel.

What my code does is importing TEK file with 1004 header number with csv format

A screenshot of the file is taken for clarification.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code opens and closes the file 2500 times for each variable.  That will create some overhead.  You may use the `"Data"` import specification for [`"CSV"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) with [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/All.html) and [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

```
{xData, yData} = 
 Transpose@
  Import[FPath <> "TEK" <> IntegerString[4, 10, 4] <> ".CSV", 
     {"Data", All, {4, 5}}]
```

Also, do not begin your symbol names with a capital letter as you can bump into issues with built-in symbols

Hope this helps.

Comment: i spent some time using python instead, python imports take only 1second and your answer helps me to use mathematica again! Mathematica is still superior over python in fitting... I took hours (with not much experience) to fit in python, but seconds in mathematica..

Comment: This import also only takes a second in *Mathematica* when it is written the *Wolfram Language* way.